# Why am I getting a jsx-loader error when I try to use react-router with webpack>

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am trying to put together a simple project with `webpack` and `react-router`.  When I am not using `react-router`, everything works fine.  Here is my code:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');

React.renderComponent(
        <h1>Hello World</h1>,
        document.body
      );
```

Here is the important part of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css'},
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' }
        ]
    }
```

But when I add `require('react-router')` to my `js` file, I get this error:

```
ERROR in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jsx-loader' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer
 @ (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 1:0-106
```

Has anyone seen this error?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have webpack installed globally and not locally? Loaders resolve like modules, so it's trying to load `jsx-loader` relative to the resource which it is applied to. Since it looks like you don't have a local version installed (you should always have one), it doesn't find it, hence its looking in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack`

There a few ways to solve this, the easiest being just simply install a local version of webpack. Or use [resolveLoader.root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) something like this to add the `node_modules` as an absolute path:

```
(resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") })
```

(see [module-loaders](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) for more info)

Comment: +1: This basically says what I said in my comment below regarding node module loading, but also has good solutions. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `webpack-dev-server`? I got this exact message when I added `react-router` to a webpack built project, but only while trying to build with a globally installed `webpack-dev-server`. Adding it to the `package.json` and installed locally fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue for me, I was using `webpack-dev-server` installed in the globally

Answer (score 3):

Have you actually run `npm install --save-dev jsx-loader`?

If it's not installed, it won't be able to find it...

Comment: yeah, I have `jsx-loader` installed

Comment: Well it looks like it's the core Node CommonJS module resolution that is failing for you here, so I guess you need to debug that. Your path there is /usr/local/lib, so you're running a webpack that was installed with `-g`. Did you install jsx-loader with `-g` also?

Comment: I am running a local `jsx-loader`.  Do I need to run a `-g` version of `jsx-loader`?

Comment: Not sure, but probably. Node module resolution via `require` does this: If the given module is not a core module (http, fs, path, etc.) then Node.js will first search for a directory named "node_modules". It will start in the current directory (relative to the **currently-executing** Javascript file in Node) and then work its way up the folder hierarchy, checking each level for a node_modules folder. It may not look in the current working directory (or in your project dir at all if you're invoking webpack from another dir), although I'm not sure as I've not read the webpack source code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm update
```

it solves the problem for me

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your review, but I have no idea what this code actually do )

It updates some broken stuff in nmp, that's all I understand.